# Server-side Long Running Tasks

Tags: architecture, microservices, architectural-patterns, service-workers

I am trying to decide on which approach to follow for long running tasks.

#### Web Client (user) story

1. Web client connects to the server (REST API + WebSocket for real-time notifications)
2. Web client POSTs a new resource intensive job request
3. Server publishes the job on a queue
4. Task worker consumes the job and processes it.
5. On Task worker job completion: 
   ***Option A***. Task worker updates DB. DB trigger fires a function to send a notification to the web client through the WebSocket connection. 
   ***Option B***. Task worker POSTs job results to the Server. Server updates DB and sends a notification to the web client through the WebSocket connection.

I have implemented both approached in separate projects and I found both to be somewhat "problematic".

#### Downsides of each approach

***Option A***:

- Task worker requires access to another service's DB, as a result coupling both services tightly to any change.
- I didn't really like using post save DB trigger to fire custom logic (e.g. send notification)

***Option B***

- The Server requires to **expose** a new endpoint, to which only the Task worker has to be able to send requests. (security concern)
- If the server is down for any reason the job result is lost (since the task worker will try to POST and no one will be there to "hear")

##### The question

Is there another option I could make use of to enhance the current solution.

[image: Architecture Alternatives]

P.S. I am certain these are pretty standard/mainstream requirements for many webapp (real-time capabilities + REST + long running server side tasks), so there has to be some *standard* approach to tackle this.

I've looking into similar questions, such as [this [1]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/438994/387652), [this [2]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/437879/387652) and  [this [3]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/315853/387652), but I hope to get a more focused answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have one queue, just add another "job finished" queue and have your backend subscribe to it and forward the messages on the websocket connection.

[image]

Fixed professional data flow diagram

Comment: True. But this means my server will do more than one things. 1. Serve HTTP requests (REST + WebSocket connections) and 2. spawn a thread(**is that what you suggest???**) to periodically consume new messages (if any). IMHO its better for each service to do one thing (just like functions).

Comment: if your server is holding the websockets connection its already got a thread running to manage that. its no extra complexity to have it subscribe to a queue for update events

Comment: although yes you could think about moving the websocket/push notification stuff to a different service. I don't think its super important though

Comment: That's what I am thinking of (i.e. moving the WebSocket to a separate service).

Comment: similarly with the task consumer updating the db directly vs through a rest call. If its strongly coupled to the microservice i don't think its a huge issue for it to write direct, although technically it would be better to send the update to the REST service for it to write it.